# Bluetooth disabled by organization. Can I attach a BT dongle and pair devices using Windows API?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, bluetooth

An organization has disabled Bluetooth on all its Windows machines. The device manager does not show any Bluetooth radios installed in the system and when the `Bluetooth and other device settings` panel is opened you are redirected to the control panel. A message in the top part of the window states that `Some settings are managed by your organization`.

When a Bluetooth dongle is attached to the system it shows up in the device manager as a Bluetooth radio. It is still not possible to access any Bluetooth control panel or settings.

I used a variant of the following program in an attempt to query Bluetooth devices. The radio is found by the program but the `BluetoothFindFirstDevice` returns `ERROR_NO_MORE_ITEMS`. If the same program is run on an unrestricted machine with the same dongle, multiple devices are found by this program.

My question is then, **is it possible to circumvent such a restriction using a Bluetooth dongle and calling the Windows API**?

Query device program (snippet copied directly from [winsocketdotnetworkprogramming.com](https://www.winsocketdotnetworkprogramming.com/winsock2programming/winsock2advancedotherprotocol4k.html)):

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <Winsock2.h>
#include <Ws2bth.h>
#include <BluetoothAPIs.h>

BLUETOOTH_FIND_RADIO_PARAMS m_bt_find_radio = {
  sizeof(BLUETOOTH_FIND_RADIO_PARAMS)
};

BLUETOOTH_RADIO_INFO m_bt_info = {
  sizeof(BLUETOOTH_RADIO_INFO),
  0
};

BLUETOOTH_DEVICE_SEARCH_PARAMS m_search_params = {
  sizeof(BLUETOOTH_DEVICE_SEARCH_PARAMS),
  1,
  0,
  1,
  1,
  1,
  15,
  NULL
};

BLUETOOTH_DEVICE_INFO m_device_info = {
  sizeof(BLUETOOTH_DEVICE_INFO),
  0
};

int main(int argc, char ** args)
{
  HANDLE m_radio = NULL;
  HBLUETOOTH_RADIO_FIND m_bt = NULL;
  HBLUETOOTH_DEVICE_FIND m_bt_dev = NULL;

  int m_radio_id;
  int m_device_id;

  DWORD mbtinfo_ret;

  // Iterate for available bluetooth radio devices in range
  // Starting from the local
  while (TRUE)
  {
    m_bt = BluetoothFindFirstRadio( & m_bt_find_radio, & m_radio);

    if (m_bt != NULL)
      printf("BluetoothFindFirstRadio() is OK!\n");
    else
      printf("BluetoothFindFirstRadio() failed with error code %d\n", GetLastError());

    m_radio_id = 0;

    do {
      // Then get the radio device info....

      mbtinfo_ret = BluetoothGetRadioInfo(m_radio, & m_bt_info);

      if (mbtinfo_ret == ERROR_SUCCESS)
        printf("BluetoothGetRadioInfo() looks fine!\n");
      else
        printf("BluetoothGetRadioInfo() failed wit herror code %d\n", mbtinfo_ret);

      wprintf(L "Radio %d:\r\n", m_radio_id);
      wprintf(L "\tInstance Name: %s\r\n", m_bt_info.szName);
      wprintf(L "\tAddress: %02X:%02X:%02X:%02X:%02X:%02X\r\n", m_bt_info.address.rgBytes[5],
        m_bt_info.address.rgBytes[4], m_bt_info.address.rgBytes[3], m_bt_info.address.rgBytes[2],
        m_bt_info.address.rgBytes[1], m_bt_info.address.rgBytes[0]);
      wprintf(L "\tClass: 0x%08x\r\n", m_bt_info.ulClassofDevice);
      wprintf(L "\tManufacturer: 0x%04x\r\n", m_bt_info.manufacturer);

      m_search_params.hRadio = m_radio;
      ZeroMemory( & m_device_info, sizeof(BLUETOOTH_DEVICE_INFO));
      m_device_info.dwSize = sizeof(BLUETOOTH_DEVICE_INFO);

      // Next for every radio, get the device
      m_bt_dev = BluetoothFindFirstDevice( & m_search_params, & m_device_info);

      if (m_bt_dev != NULL)
        printf("\nBluetoothFindFirstDevice() is working!\n");
      else
        printf("\nBluetoothFindFirstDevice() failed with error code %d\n", GetLastError());

      m_radio_id++;
      m_device_id = 0;

      // Get the device info
      do
      {
        wprintf(L "\n\tDevice %d:\r\n", m_device_id);
        wprintf(L "  \tInstance Name: %s\r\n", m_device_info.szName);
        wprintf(L "  \tAddress: %02X:%02X:%02X:%02X:%02X:%02X\r\n", m_device_info.Address.rgBytes[5],
          m_device_info.Address.rgBytes[4], m_device_info.Address.rgBytes[3], m_device_info.Address.rgBytes[2],
          m_device_info.Address.rgBytes[1], m_device_info.Address.rgBytes[0]);
        wprintf(L "  \tClass: 0x%08x\r\n", m_device_info.ulClassofDevice);
        wprintf(L "  \tConnected: %s\r\n", m_device_info.fConnected ? L "true" : L "false");
        wprintf(L "  \tAuthenticated: %s\r\n", m_device_info.fAuthenticated ? L "true" : L "false");
        wprintf(L "  \tRemembered: %s\r\n", m_device_info.fRemembered ? L "true" : L "false");

        m_device_id++;

        // Well, the found device information can be used for further socket
        // operation such as creating a socket, bind, listen, connect, send, receive etc..

        // If no more device, exit the loop
        if (!BluetoothFindNextDevice(m_bt_dev, & m_device_info))
          break;

      } while (BluetoothFindNextDevice(m_bt_dev, & m_device_info));

      // NO more device, close the device handle
      if (BluetoothFindDeviceClose(m_bt_dev) == TRUE)
        printf("\nBluetoothFindDeviceClose(m_bt_dev) is OK!\n");
      else
        printf("\nBluetoothFindDeviceClose(m_bt_dev) failed with error code %d\n", GetLastError());

    } while (BluetoothFindNextRadio( & m_bt_find_radio, & m_radio));

    // No more radio, close the radio handle
    if (BluetoothFindRadioClose(m_bt) == TRUE)
      printf("BluetoothFindRadioClose(m_bt) is OK!\n");
    else
      printf("BluetoothFindRadioClose(m_bt) failed with error code %d\n", GetLastError());

    // Exit the outermost WHILE and BluetoothFindXXXXRadio loops if there is no more radio
    if (!BluetoothFindNextRadio( & m_bt_find_radio, & m_radio))
      break;

    // Give some time for the 'signal' which is a typical for crap wireless devices
    Sleep(1000);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: ***is it possible to circumvent such a restriction using a Bluetooth dongle and calling the Windows API?*** I would expect the answer is no.

Comment: Try WinSock Bluetooth API: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/bluetooth/bluetooth-and-wsalookupservicebegin

Comment: If this is just for local development, can you just delete the Group Policy registry that's hiding Bluetooth?

Comment: Windows doesn't really care HOW a BT radio is attached to the computer, whether it is built-in to the motherboard or attached via USB.  A BT radio is still a BT radio, and the organization policy is clearly blocking access to BT radios in general.

Comment: I agree that makes sense, but I was hoping for some more concrete documentation on this. What does not make sense for me though is that the built in radio does not register with this program - only the dongle does.

Comment: @transporter_room_3 When you attach the Bluetooth dongle, can you discover this Windows machine externally, for example, from a phone?